Logic Puzzle with truths & lies to questions
Puzzle :
We are at a crossroad of 2 paths. One path leads to a swamp and one path leads to the treasure.
At the crossroad we meet 2 people , of whom we know that 1 is always telling the truth and 1 is always lying.
Do we have to ask in total more than 2 questions to figure out the path to the treasure?
My attempt :
Suppose I ask Person A and Person B : Does the left path lead to the treasure then obviously we will get a Yes/No from A and No/Yes from B depending on who is the liar.
So we can not know which path is correct.
I thought of asking A : Does the right path lead to the treasure?and B:does the left path lead to the treasure.
Now the answers will be No/No or Yes/Yes so we still can not know which path to follow.
So I guess we need more than 2 questions to figure out the correct path?

This is a classic riddle, repeated and even parodied multiple times throughout popular culture. https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/2188/two-doors-with-two-guards-one-lies-one-tells-the-truth is one place it is discussed.

It even appears in an old Doctor Who episode

Ah thanks a lot....

CORE IDEA :
$\lnot [ \lnot X ] \equiv X$
Hence you can ask Single Question which itself contains a question to get the truth
Consider this :
If I ask you whether left goes to treasure , what would you say ?
A liar would lie to the inner question , which would have to get negated to reply to outer question. We will get the truth.
The non-liar would always tell the truth to inner question & to outer question. We will get the truth.

The more traditional solution is to ask what the other person would say if asked which direction led to the treasure. However, this version which asks what the person themself would answer has the added advantage of working when they are alone. It even works for someone who randomly decides beforehand whether to tell the truth or to tell a lie to the next question.

That is Correct , @PaulSinclair , more-over , this way has added advantage too : the answerer need not know whether the other is a liar or not ! [[ Puzzle Variations & Solution Variations Exist ]]
